# How can I bold text in all cells in one specific column when using React Table library?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

How would I go about bolding the text in all of the cells in one specific column in a table? In general, how would I style the cells of a specific column in a table. By the way, I'm using v7 of the React Table library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `columns` array you can add the following to the column you'd like to become bold:

```js
Cell: ({ value }) => <b>{value}</b>
```

You can find a complete example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-worker-txl91?file=/src/App.js